# importing and manipulating data file

Tags: import, data

I have a large text file containing numeric data of 1000 groups each of 200 lines. The lines are unsorted. There is a 9 line header at the beginning of each group, i.e., 209 ⨉ 1000 lines altogether.

I want to drop the headers to have a file containing 200 ⨉ 1000 lines. I also want the 200 lines of each output group sorted by the first number in the line. What is a way to do this efficiently in *Mathematica*?

My actual data set is much larger than 200 lines and 1000 groups. I made up these number for the sake of discussion.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `Read`, `ReadList`, `Skip`, etc.?

Comment: Could you put a large text file on dropbox or somewhere else so we can play with it?

Comment: here is the link to a file with 134 steps each 1584 lines (including 9 header lines). I want 134*1575 lines sorted 1,2,3...1575,1,2,3,...1575,...(ex. first 1575 lines are ordered)

cheers,

Comment: sorry, forgot to add link in previous comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1b12qxlowdcccm/2.txt

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the fastest way, but this just takes a few minutes to write.
Read and looping and checking will be faster, but takes more time to code.

Since I could not use Import on your dropbox link, I copied 2.txt to my website.
Then, if you have a fast internet connection and reasonable hardware,
the following should run in less than 10 seconds. Fast enough?

```
dat = Import["http://www.mertig.com/2.txt", "Table"];
sdat= Sort /@ 
   Select[SplitBy[dat, MatchQ[#, {__?NumberQ}] &], Length[#] > 10 &];

Dimensions@sdat

(*
===> {134, 1575, 5}
*)
```

Comment: Thanks. this works well. although I intended to know how to do this in a  "loop".

Comment: Why use loops if you don't have to?

Comment: alright, the text file I'm trying to import is too big (4GB). but I need only (i*1575) + (10th and 1575th) lines. {i,0,10000}. 
importing it uses memory in very huge files and crashes. can I read only lines and select?

Comment: @SesnaSecna you can. no time right now. later.